# How to get data from sql limited to the rows in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have created a dataframe which has some 2K accounts.

The sample data looks like this -

```
Acct ID
1002
1005
1007
1009
```

I have odbc connection and i want to get usage data which looks like following

```
Acct ID      Start Date      End Date     Usage
1001         10/1/2019      11/01/2019    100
1001         11/01/2019     12/01/2019    120
1002         02/02/2019     03/01/2019    300
1002         03/02/2019     04/01/2019    450
1003         05/10/2018     06/09/2018    225
1004         07/15/2018     08/13/2018    100
1005         11/12/2019     12/11/2019     50
1006         
1007
1008
1009
```

However to get this data the sql pull will take a long time. I want to limit it to the accounts in my dataframe. Basically it should get info for these accounts only - 1002,1005,1007,1009

How would I do this

Comment: Instead of change in R, better use `where` clause in sql because there it is taking tiume. So you need just `where Acct_ID in (1002,1005,1007,1009)`

Comment: I have 2K accounts and that will not be efficient either

Comment: `paste(df$Acct_ID, collapse = ",")` help making the sql query...

Comment: Thanks cory for responding. where should i use this paste comment in the sql query

Answer (score 1):

You can build your WHERE clause using the vector of account IDs.

```
query <- 
  paste0("SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [AcctID] IN (", 
         paste0(Dframe$AcctID, collapse = ", "), ")")

query
[1] "SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [AcctID] IN (1002, 1005, 1007, 1009)"
```

This will work for numeric values in the WHERE clause.  If you need to filter by strings, you can do a similar pattern, but need to 1) insert single quotes around the values, and 2) evaluate your risk of SQL Injection attacks.

Parameterized queries are useful here, but the code looks a bit more heinous. This should work for both numeric and string WHERE clauses.

```
library(DBI)

conn <- dbConnect(...) # make your ODBC connection

Dframe <- data.frame(AcctID = c(1002, 1005, 1007, 1009))


param_list <- lapply(Dframe$AcctID, identity)
names(param_list) <- sprintf("x%s", seq_along(Dframe$AcctID))

query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [AcctID] IN (", 
                paste0(sprintf("?%s", names(param_list)), collapse = ", "), ")")

Out <- 
  dbGetQuery(
    conn,
    sqlInterpolate(
      conn,
      query, 
      .dots = param_list
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I am getting the following error - Error in dbGetQuery(conn, sqlInterpolate(conn, query, .dots = param_list)) : 
  object 'conn' not found

I am assuming the odbc connection I am creating is not working well with dbGetQuery

Comment: `conn` (or whatever object name you use) should be a valid ODBC connection.  How are you making or ODBC connection?

Comment: library(RODBC)

con <-odbcConnect("DSN NAME", uid="", pwd="")

Comment: I tried again and got this error -
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sqlInterpolate’ for signature ‘"RODBC"’

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up with `RODBC` and `DBI` packages.  I recommend using the `DBI` package for this scenario, and connecting with `dbConnect`. I've modified my answer to reflect this.  See `?dbConnect` for making your connection.

Comment: Thank you for your help Benjamin. I figured out the DBI connection. However, i got another error -
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: HY000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00939: too many arguments for function

Comment: I think that probably ought to be turned into its own question.  I have no experience with Oracle database connections.

Comment: So this is happening because of having rows more than 1000. Is there workaround where I can do it for any number of rows.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't encountered that before.  Makes sense, though, that the query may not want to bind more than 1000 parameters.  If it were me, I'd write a loop to bind up to 900 parameters at time.  My code attempted to do it all in one call to the database.  But if you end up making four or five calls, that's still better than doing a call to the database for each condition.